# SmartGWT vs. GXT Selenium Support

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, smartgwt, selenium-ide, gxt

Just working on a comparison between the two with regards to their support for selenium tests.  It seems like a bit of a wash...on one hand you've got convoluted custom xpaths in SmartGWT that require the IDE to properly locate them.  Our shop doesn't plan on using the IDE tool a great deal and would prefer to just code our tests from scratch if possible.  This means recording a rough test in the IDE, and then hacking it up after.

On the other side is GXT which would require us to set custom ID's on any element we plan on testing in Selenium.  This is cumbersome, and yes, we wouldn't be able able to easily access some generated elements (message boxes perhaps?), but the benefit is that if I know my ID names, I can easily construct tests without having to refer back to the IDE constantly.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Locating elements by their IDs is the way you want to go.  It's the fastest technique, across all browsers.  Complicated XPath or CSS selectors tend to be much more "brittle" (*i.e.*, more likely to break as you make changes in the application), and XPath is S-L-O-W when you're testing in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Do you know if SmartGWT XPath's are faster than browser XPaths?  Perhaps I mispoke by calling them XPath's, as SmartGWT's locator (scLocator) does not use a browsers actual XPath api from my limited knowledge.  I called them XPath's as they are similar in nature (nested structures it appears that could still suffer from the issue of specifying the entire path to an element, and then having something in that path/tree change).